# ProgressDialog not being displayed in Activity with custom View

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-asynctask

I am developing an Android app which has 2 classes. Game, which extends Activity, and GameView, which extends View.

When the game is loaded, it sets the content view to GameView, which is just a drawing class that uses a canvas to display the game.

I am trying to create a ProgressDialog in the Game class which will show a spinner after a certain action has been done, as this takes a long time to complete. So far I have the following:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
pd.setMessage("Calculating hint");
pd.show();
AsyncTask<String[][], Void, SudokuSquare> nextSquareThread = new GetNextSquare().execute(puzzleNumbers);
next = nextSquareThread.get();
pd.dismiss();
setContentView(gameView);
```

And my AsyncTask class looks like this:

```
private class GetNextSquare extends AsyncTask<String[][], Void, SudokuSquare> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Game.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Finding next number");
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected SudokuSquare doInBackground(final String[][]... args) {
        try {
            SudokuAdvancedSolver solver = new SudokuSolver(args[0]);
            return solver.getOneValue();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final SudokuSquare result) {

        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment I have two ProgressDialogs, one inside the AsyncTask and one outside. Which one is correct? Also, the spinner is not being displayed at all. What am I overlooking which is causing this to be the case?

Answer (score 0):

only the one outside is correct. because you are trying the main thread (the UI thread of your activity) by another thread (your asychronic task). you should use a handler in place of this :
1/ you show the progress bar
2/ you load the game in a thread
3/ when the game is loaded you send a message to the handler which will stop the progress bar.

See this [exemple](http://androidexample.com/Thread_With_Handlers_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=58&aaid=83) . you should dismiss your dialog in the handler (when the handler receives the message from the thread) .

Answer (score 0):

If you don't implement a listener on Asynctask, i could suggest you to dismiss your progress dialog onPostExecute

```
private ProgressDialog dialog;

public void setProgressDialog(ProgressDialog dialog){
    this.dialog = dialog;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final SudokuSquare result) {
dialog.dismiss();       
}
```

and before you executing Asynctask add this code

```
nextSquareThread.setProgressDialog(pd);
```